# $.ajax success callback not firing in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, cross-browser

I'm having an issue where my call to $.ajax is completing successfully and returning content with a response of 200OK as reported by firebug, but the success,complete and error callbacks do not execute.  This is only happening in firefox, in chrome it works fine (i am running firefox22).

```
$.ajax(site_url+url+'/fetch_salt',{type:'POST',data:data,success:check_salt});
var group = '';

function check_salt(d)
{
    console.log(d);
```

The actual response for the request as reported by firebug is:

```
choose_login:{"admin":"Admin Zone"}
```

And response type:

```
Content-Type    text/html
```

I have tried forcing settings like dataType and contentType in case jquery is assuming json or something and I have tried anonymous functions for the error, success and complete callbacks, but nothing works.

Am posting full function code, just in case its some kind of syntax error quirk:

```
function prep_login_form(elem,url,challenge)
{
    function show_error(msg)
    {
        $(elem).find('.ecms-error-for-password .ecms-error-text').html(msg).closest('.ecms-error-container').removeClass('ecms-error-hidden');
    }

    function submit()
    {
        var data = {email:$(elem).find('input[name="email"]').val()};
        data[csfr_token_name] = csfr_hash;
        $.ajax({type:'POST',url:site_url+url+'/attempt_login',data:data,success:check_salt});
        var group = '';

        function check_salt(d)
        {
            console.log(d);
            if (d=='no_email')
            {
                show_error('Invalid Email address');
            }
            else if (d=='account_disabled')
            {
                show_error('This account has been disabled, please contact your administrator');
            }
            else if (d.substr(0,12)=='choose_login')
            {
                var cl;
                eval('cl = '+d.substr(13));
                var cou = 0;
                for (p in cl)
                {
                    cou++;
                }
                if (cou==1)
                {
                    group = p;
                    var mydata = $.extend(data,{group:p});
                    $.ajax(site_url+url+'/fetch_salt',{type:'POST',data:mydata,success:check_salt})
                }
                else
                {
                    var str = '<div class="login-selection-popup"><p>We have detected that your email address is linked to more than one account.<br />Please select which zone you would like to login to.</p><ul class="choose-login-popup">';
                    for (p in cl)
                    {
                        str+='<li><a rel="'+p+'">'+cl[p]+'</a></li>';
                    }
                    str+='</ul></div>';
                    open_modal({heading:'Choose Account',content:str,buttons:function(close_modal)
                    {
                        $(this).find('.choose-login-popup').on('click','a',function()
                        {
                            group = $(this).attr('rel');
                            var mydata = $.extend(data,{group:$(this).attr('rel')});
                            $.ajax(site_url+url+'/fetch_salt',{type:'POST',data:mydata,success:check_salt})
                            close_modal();
                        });
                    }});
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var salt = d;
                var pw = $(elem).find('input[name="password"]').val();
                data.password = hex_md5(challenge+hex_md5(salt+pw));
                data.group = group;
                $.ajax(site_url+url+'/attempt_login',{type:'POST',data:data,success:function(d)
                {
                    if (d=='no_email')
                    {
                        show_error('Invalid username or password');//Invalid Email address
                    }
                    else if (d=='account_disabled')
                    {
                        show_error('This account has been disabled, please contact your administrator');
                    }
                    else if (d=='invalid_login')
                    {
                        show_error('Invalid username or password');//Email or Password did not match
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        window.location.href = d;
                    }
                }});
            }
        }
    }

    $(elem).on('keyup','input',function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode=='13')
        {
            submit();
        }
    });
    $(elem).find('.login-submit').on('click',function()
    {
        submit();
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the error callback? Maybe there's an error you're not noticing yet.

Comment: *"I have tried anonymous functions for the error,"* the error callback should have at least triggered, even if it doesn't always give useful information.

Comment: Try by this: `$.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: site_url+url+'/fetch_salt', data: data, success: check_salt});`

Comment: Hi like i said I have tried setting a callback for the error function, it doesn't fire and it in any case executes the success callback in chrome.

Comment: Have you tried monitoring the network traffic in the browsers debug tool or with Fiddler to see what's happening?

Comment: What do you mean by monitoring network traffic? I am currently using firebug's 'net' panel to watch the ajax call and it did fire, did return the response text and header I indicated in my post and did have a status of 200

Comment: If you try to run `check_salt( 'blah' )` from the developer console, does it do something? Could it be that `check_salt` is `undefined` in your ajax call in firefox, either due to nested functions or due to the fact that your ajax call is before the function is defined?

Comment: That is some crazy, crazy logic there. Why is the function called `check_salt` when it's really a *massive* AJAX success callback with **way** more responsibility than just checking a salt? Why are you attempting to hash/salt the password client-side? Why are you sending the salt across the wire in (presumably) plain-text? Why are you using MD5 as your password-hashing algorithm? If you need to hide data in transit, you need to use SSL, not JavaScript, which fundamentally *cannot* deliver the security you're looking for.

Comment: have you tried defining the function before calling $.post? javascript can sometimes be picky in the order the code is placed.

Comment: Sumurai8 - check_salt cannot be run from developer console, it is a nested function.
meager - the check_salt function was originally doing just that but eventually progressed into something else and was never renamed, and besides I don't think this is the place to be arguing security best practices my question is in relation to why I cant get the success callback to work
NDM - I have just tested putting the function before, it made no difference and it shouldn't matter, like i said in my post I have tried useing an anonymous function instead and it did not work either.

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble guys I recently had addware on my PC and battled to get rid of it. I think that it had damaged/hijacked my firefox. After re-installing firefox the problem has gone away, the callbacks now execute.

I will post this answer after the 8 hours has expired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for all the trouble guys I recently had addware on my PC and battled to get rid of it.  I think that it had damaged/hijacked my firefox.  After re-installing firefox the problem has gone away, the callbacks now execute.